# WordPress 125% duplicates widgets / Change Media breakpoints

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, responsive-design

//Initial situation - What I have and what I want

I am using WordPress version 5.1.1 with the Elementor Page Builder Plugin version 2.5.8 and I want to make a responsive website looking good on both desktop and mobile, tablet as well.

So I have a section with two columns within the row where below is the same system for 2 more times on desktop view. When it comes to mobile, I want a different adjustment.

so the trick I use is, I duplicate the widget and align the elements within the second section and set the first one to hide on mobile and the second to hide on desktop and tablet. So far so good, it seems all working.

//The problem - What doesn't work and needs to be fixed

As I told above, the system I use seems to be working, on mobile it only shows the second section, on desktop only the first. Tested on 100% size in the windows display settings and zoom in the browser and separate browsers.

BUT When it comes to 125% in the windows display settings and I split the page via the windows function to half of the screen, it shows both sections which either doesn't look good and really isn't what I want and need. It only happens with Google Chrome browser, all others "decide" which device it's using at the moment, only chrome shows on 125% AND half screen at the same time both sections.

What can I do / How can I fix this issue?
Edge eg. sets on the half screen to tablet while Chrome is still in Desktop.
MAybe it has something to do with Madia breakpoints? Can I change them in WP-Settings?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Edit: Pictures to show what it kinda looks like:

[This is the standard desktop view of this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo4os.png)

[This is the standard tablet view of the second section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1ZVS.png)

[This is how it looks in Google Chrome 125% Windows 100% Browser Zoom Half Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u581.jpg)

Don't have any manual media queries, they're all standard. Works with all on 100% Windows resolution, only on 125% Google Chrome it's weird.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add screenshots and possibly a scribble? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Kichen and welcome to SO, as @jasie said, see How to Ask. Show us the code specific to your widgets and the associated media queries so we can see what's going on.